# .NET Core 2.2 API on IIS returns error if it attempts to connect to Db but otherwise works fine

Tags: asp.net-core

When I publish my .NET core app to a development IIS server, I make a call to the API and the method works fine locally.  This method makes a Db call using a connection string stored in 
appSettings.json as well as appSettings.Development.json

Observations:
- Yes, I have ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development and I have both an appSettings.json file AND appSettings.Development.json file
- So I started looking at the published files and I had BOTH of these json files in the published folder, even though appSettings.Development.json properties is set to "Build Action" = content and Copy to Output Directory = Do Not Copy
- If I comment out the code that his the Db, and return dummy data, and republish the api, i get the results fine with no complaints about "development mode"

***Error I get when calling the API trying to hit the Db***

Error.

An error occurred while processing your request.

**Request ID:**
    `0HLL1GOCEHH73:00000001`

#### Development Mode

Swapping to the 
    **Development** environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred.

**The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.**
    It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
    For local debugging, enable the
    **Development** environment by setting the
    **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** environment variable to
    **Development**
    and restarting the app.

**Questions**:
- The Db connection strings are in both

[ **update** ]

Brain-fart!  The db connection strings were using 'trusted', so no wonder they worked locally!  Once I put in the credentials, and re-published, things worked like I expected.  However, the error message threw me off.

Im still not sure why I have both of those appSettings files published?  Which one will it use?

Comment: the db call works locally?

Comment: See update above

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming your appsetting files are named as following:

1. appSettings.json
2. appSettings.dev.json

typically, you have to explicitly set the environment to dev. if you use Visual Studio for development, it sets an environment variable that tells the application to put it in dev mode.

Without seeing the initializing logic, I would say in prod it will use the appSettings.json.

[Take a look at this article, it explains configuration in more details.](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2018/06/20/microsoft-extensions-configuration-deep-dive/)

Comment: Yes, I have set my ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable in the IDE to "Development", so I was assuming that when I publish my app, that settings in appSettings.Develop.json would replace values in appSettings.json and THAT file would be published to the target.  However, BOTH files go over.

Comment: Your CI/CD pipeline should remove that file. Whether you do that manually or through some automated process. Develop.json would replace values in the other json file. You want those values to be different. The difference in environments.